# How does return work in this Grails case?

Tags: grails, groovy

I'm a Grails / Groovy newb and I'm tracing through some pre-existing code.

It looks like this:

```
def update(Long id, Long version) {
        def skateBoardSkillsInstance = SkateBoardSkills.get(id)
        if (!skateBoardSkillsInstance) {
            flash.message = message(code: 'default.not.found.message', args: [message(code: 'skateBoardSkills.label', default: 'SkateBoardSkills'), id])
            redirect(action: "list")
            return
        }

        if (version != null) {
            if (skateBoardSkillsInstance.version > version) {
                skateBoardSkillsInstance.errors.rejectValue("version", "default.optimistic.locking.failure",
                          [message(code: 'skateBoardSkills.label', default: 'SkateBoardSkills')] as Object[],
                          "Another user has updated this SkateBoardSkills while you were editing")
                render(view: "edit", model: [skateBoardSkillsInstance: skateBoardSkillsInstance])
                return
            }
        }

        skateBoardSkillsInstance.properties = params

        if (!skateBoardSkillsInstance.save(flush: true)) {
            render(view: "edit", model: [skateBoardSkillsInstance: skateBoardSkillsInstance])
            return
        }

        flash.message = message(code: 'default.updated.message', args: [message(code: 'skateBoardSkills.label', default: 'SkateBoardSkills'), skateBoardSkillsInstance.id])
        redirect(action: "show", id: skateBoardSkillsInstance.id)
    }
```

The surprise for me was when I traced to the first return. It seems to execute the return and then I'm in the next if.  Why didn't it return?

[Edit] I've made the example more detailed.

OK, upon closer (and earlier in the day) examination, a more accurate description of what I'm seeing is this.  I trace to an 'if' condition. It's evaluated. If the condition is false, the debugger skips the block but stops at the return statement inside the block. Very confusing. Was the block skipped or wasn't it? I'll try putting some break points inside the block. In the case where the 'if' statement is true, it executes the block and does appear to return... however there are two steps that aren't showing up. The execution point disappears. That means I have to hit F8 twice and then it returns. Suspect that is some Groovy magic going on though. Something is getting put in there by the system.

Comment: If the condition was met, it did, and whatever you're traceing it with is wrong

Comment: Certainly possible but doesn't seem likely. If I were tracing code that didn't match the binary, things would happen like I would see values that are clearly wrong or I would see break points or steps show up on empty lines. I'll keep an open mind about that but I think it's probably something I don't get about Groovy and the return keyword.

Comment: What IDE you are using? The solution may differ between different IDEs.

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA 2016.2.4.

Comment: Another reason for skepticism is that this method has yet to change since it was first compiled on this machine. It's never been different.

Answer (score 1):

It is not related to the return in Groovy. There main reason for the situation you have is a bad synchronization between the code you are running in debug mode and the IDE code updates in your build directory. 
That looks strange but there are some good techniques to solve it (although it is not covers 100% of the synchronization of your code line).
The changes in your code between different runs of your code are not compiled completely into the build directory and small changes in the build directories cause that behavior you have.
The easiest way to solve that is by enforcing new complete build of your code, and it can be done by deletion of your 'build' directory and rerun the program on debug mode.
If that is not helping try to refresh the project dependencies before rerun the application.

Comment: What is the IDE you are using? What is the Groovy version? Are you working with Grails? What is the building tool you are working with? (gradle/maven)?

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA 2016.2.4. as mentioned in comments. Groovy Version: 2.4.7 JVM: 1.8.0_101

Comment: That reason may be due to some different parameters so all together may complete the picture to get the issue be solved

Comment: It's an old Grails project. Grails version: 2.5.4

Comment: Great Choosing of IDEA. Are you using Gradle? Grails? Grails 2.4 ? or greater?

Comment: Try to put your mouse on the main directory and right click on it. there should be grails-command lineThan right 'refresh-dependencies'

Comment: Under the 'file' tab there is the 'Invalidate caches and restrat' press it and restart your project

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125375/discussion-between-user447607-and-rotemy).